# Normalization of integrand for numerical integration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

First off, I'm not sure if this is the best place to post this, but since there isn't a dedicated Matlab community I'm posting this here.

To give a little background, I'm currently prototyping a plasma physics simulation which involves triple integration. The innermost integral can be done analytically, but for the outer two this is just impossible. I always thought it's best to work with values close to unity and thus normalized the my innermost integral such that it is unit-less and usually takes values close to unity. However, compared to an earlier version of the code where the this innermost integral evaluated to values of the order of 1e-50, the numerical double integration, which uses the native Matlab function `integral2` with target relative tolerance of 1e-6, now requires around 1000 times more function evaluations to converge. As a consequence my simulation now takes roughly 12h instead of the previous 20 minutes.

**Question**

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible that the faster convergence in the older version is simply due to the additional evaluations vanishing as roundoff errors and that the results thus arn't trustworthy even though it passes the 1e-6 relative tolerance? In the few tests I run the results seemed to be the same in both versions though.
2. What is the best practice concerning the normalization of the integrand for numerical integration?
3. Is there some way to improve the convergence of numerical integrals, especially if the integrand might have singularities?

I'm thankful for any help or insight, especially since I don't fully understand the inner workings of Matlab's `integral2` function and what should be paid attention to when using it.
If I didn't know any better I would actually conclude, that the integrand which is of the order of 1e-50 works way better than one of say the order of 1e+0, but that doesn't seem to make sense. Is there some numerical reason why this could actually be the case?

**TL;DR** when multiplying the function to be integrated numerically by Matlab 's `integral2` with a factor 1e-50 and then the result in turn with a factor 1e+50, the integral gives the same result but converges way faster and I don't understand why.

*edit:*
I prepared a short script to illustrate the problem. Here the relative difference between the two results was of the order of 1e-4 and thus below the actual relative tolerance of `integral2`. In my original problem however the difference was even smaller.

```
fun = @(x,y,l) l./(sqrt(1-x.*cos(y)).^5).*((1-x).*sin(y));

x = linspace(0,1,101);
y = linspace(0,pi,101).';
figure
surf(x,y,fun(x,y,1));

l = linspace(0,1,101); l=l(2:end);
v1 = zeros(1,100); v2 = v1;

tval = tic;
for i=1:100
    fun1 = @(x,y) fun(x,y,l(i));
    v1(i) = integral2(fun1,0,1,0,pi,'RelTol',1e-6);
end
t1 = toc(tval)

tval = tic;
for i=1:100
    fun1 = @(x,y) 1e-50*fun(x,y,l(i));
    v2(i) = 1e+50*integral2(fun1,0,1,0,pi,'RelTol',1e-6);
end
t2 = toc(tval)

figure
hold all;
plot(l,v1);
plot(l,v2);
plot(l,abs((v2-v1)./v1));
```